# Character Pointer to strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, pointer-to-array

This is C code snippet:

```
 int main()
 {
   char *names=[ "tom", "jerry", "scooby" ];
   printf("%s", *names[0]);// prints t
   printf("%s", *names[1]);// prints j
  // how to print full word "tom", or full word "jerry"
}
```

As stated earlier, I want my output to be:
tom
jerry
scooby
So using pointers how do I print the whole thing?

Comment: Change `char *names` to `char *names[]`. Remove `*` before `printf` arguments. Look at this: http://ideone.com/bokCN5

Comment: change `names` to be an array of pointer, otherwise it can only hold 1 string. Also the `[` should be a `{`.

Comment: @ashley It looks like you should re-read the chapter of your C book that explains strings.

Comment: Also, use `{}` instead of `[]` to enclose intializers.

Answer (score 3):

Does it compile? Because your array initialization is not correct.
To properly declare an array and print them, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *names[]= { "tom", "jerry", "scooby" };
   printf("%s %s %s\n", names[0], names[1], names[2]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to add the [].

Comment: Can you tell me the output of

Comment: Can you tell me the output of: printf("%s\n",names[0])?

Comment: Thanks, it is tom and jerry. Thank you very much. Have a great day.

Comment: `names[0]` is the first element in the array `names` and is a pointer to a string literal. Printing `names[0]` would print `tom`.